# Monotonic Union of Submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules

The theorem is:

Suppose $M$ is an $R$-module, $T$ is an index set, and for each $t \in T$, $N_t$ is a submodule of $M$. If $\{N_t\}$ is a monotonic collection, $\cup_{t\in T} N_t$ is a submodule.

Is the following proof correct?

If $a, b \in \cup_{t\in T} N_t$, then $a, b \in N_t$ for some $t$. Then $a+b\in N_t$.

If $c\in \cup_{t\in T}N_t$, then $c\in N_t$ for some $t$, then $cr\in N_t$, then $cr\in \cup_{t\in T}N_t$.

...

Similar proof for the other criteria to be a module.

...

Is it somewhat too trivial to be a theorem?

Comment: What is your definition of "monotonic"? For the two possibilities I can think of, the argument looks okay. You didn't say what $r$ is but, assuming it to be a member of your ring $R$, it's fine. It's a bit obvious, but you might also note that your union is not empty, and that $a+b$ is in the union at the end of the first step. I think a theorem should be either somewhat surprising or useful, and this fits the latter.

Answer (score 0):

*Getting this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

Yes, the proof is fine for proving that the union of a nondecreasing chain of submodules is a submodule. Although easy to prove, it turns out to be very useful. For example, it pops up when using Zorn's lemma to show rings with identity have maximal right ideals.